# Ratio of absolutely continuous functions on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

### Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and $g > 0$. Prove that the ratio $\frac{f}{g}$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$.

I've tried using the property that a function, $h$, is absolutely continuous if and only if 
$h(x) = h(a) + \int_{a}^{x}r(t)dt$.

But that hasn't seemed to go anywhere.

I've also seen where it's shown that the product of two absolutely continuous functions is absolutely continuous. That method involves showing that both functions are bounded and mining the definition of absolute continuity, which I also haven't gotten to work.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $g$ is continuous it has  a positive minimum, say $c$. Hence $\sum |\frac 1 {g(a_i)}-\frac 1 {g(b_i)}| \leq \sum\frac 1 {c^{2}} |g(a_i)-g(b_i)|$. Conclude from this that $\frac 1 g$ is absolutely continuous. Since $\frac f g =f \frac 1 g$ it follows that  $\frac f g$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you forgot a difference sign in the first sum.  i.e. $\sum \left| \frac{1}{g(a_i)} - \frac{1}{g(b_i)} \right|$. Other than that this is great.